# Data Types in C++

Tags: c++, .net

I am working on an assignment to Fill in the blank Data Types. 
I have reread the small chapters numerous times in "Learn C++ for Game Development" 
and tried various types but,
My issue is calling the color Green from the 
Enum.

Here is the original code:

```
// DataTypes.cpp : The data types to declare each of the variables is missing.
// Based on the value being stored in the variable and the comments beside it, 
// fill in the data type at the beginning of each line.  Then compile and run 
// program to make sure you selected the correct types.
//
// After you submit your answers, try changing the values stored in the
// variables.  What can you learn about the different data types?
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int atgc, const char * arg[])
{
 classAverage = 90.7f; //Decimal number
 letterScore = 'A'; //Single letter
 testScore = 95; //Whole number value
 classTestAverage = 88.4f; //Decimal number, notice the 'f' at the end
 colorCode{
    Green = 1,
    Yellow = 5,
    Red = 10
} gradebookColor; //Stores list of values
gradebookColor = Green; //This line does not need a declaration, it was declared in the line above
 isStudentPassing = true; //Could be true or false

cout << "The class average is currently "
    << classAverage
    << endl;
cout << "The class test average was "
    << classTestAverage
    << endl;
cout << "Your test score was "
    << testScore
    << endl;
cout << "Your current letter score is "
    << letterScore
    << endl;
cout << "The color of your gradebook entry is "
    << gradebookColor
    << endl;
cout << "Are you passing? "
    << boolalpha        //This line allows the word 'true' or 'false' to be printed instead of '0' or '1'
    << isStudentPassing
    << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Here is what I have completed so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int atgc, const char * arg[])
{
 float classAverage = 90.7f; //Decimal number
 char letterScore = 'A'; //Single letter
 int testScore = 95; //Whole number value
 float classTestAverage = 88.4f; //Decimal number, notice the 'f' at the end
 enum class colorCode {
     Green = 1,
     Yellow = 5,
     Red = 10
 };

unsigned int gradebookColor; //Stores list of values
 colorCode gradebookColor = colorCode::Green; //This line errors out     bool isStudentPassing = true; //Could be true or false
cout << "The class average is currently "
    << classAverage
    << endl;
cout << "The class test average was "
    << classTestAverage
    << endl;
cout << "Your test score was "
    << testScore
    << endl;
cout << "Your current letter score is "
    << letterScore
    << endl;
cout << "The color of your gradebook entry is "
    << gradebookColor
    << endl;
cout << "Are you passing? "
    << boolalpha        //This line allows the word 'true' or 'false' to be printed instead of '0' or '1'
    << isStudentPassing
    << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I know I  am not understanding how to call the  color Green. I have tried various combinations suggested in the book, but nothing seems to work.

Please help so I can fix this and understand why.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `colorCode gradebookColor = colorCode::Green`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ceros says in the comment, you need to append the enum type :

```
colorCode gradebookColor = colorCode::Green;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that. I still receive the same error:  Green: undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of your variable.

```
enum colorCode
{
  Green = 1
};

colorCode gradebookColor = colorCode::Green;

std::cout << gradebookColor << std::endl;
```

Will output "1"

Comment: I changed my enum class to enum so the int gradebookColor will be accepted, but it will not print out "green".

Comment: enum colorCode {
   Green = 1,
   Yellow = 5,
   Red = 10
  };
  
  unsigned int gradebookColor; //Stores list of values
  colorCode gradebookColor = colorCode::Green; //This line does not need a declaration, it was declared in the line above
  bool isStudentPassing = true; //Could be true or false

Comment: @rmac This `unsigned int gradebookColor = colorCode::Green;` works. Also, a print to console will never print the string representation of the enum, only it's numerical value sadly.

Comment: @rmac and you cannot declare twice the same variable. `unsigned int gradebookColor;` followed by `colorCode gradebookColor;` You will get a compiler error

Answer (score 1):

When you define an `enum class` you have to prepend the name of the `enum` to access its values: `colorCode::Green`. You could also define your `enum` without the `class` specifier, then the name is optional. However, keep in mind that the `enum` is then implicitly convertible from and to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

data types:--Data types are means to identify the type of data and associated operations for handling it.
basically two types of data types
1. fundamental  data types (int, char, bool, float, double, void)
2.derived data types(array,pointer,struct,class etc)
for more detail in simple language click on the link given below
https://simplifiedtutorial4u.blogspot.in/2017/08/data-types-in-c.html